# How to load local hosted site in browser

Tags: php, localhost

I'm a newbie programmer trying to build a demo PHP site on my computer (a mac) following a tutorial, but (following the instructions of the tutor) I can't load the first page into my browser.

I have the files stored in a folder called "photo_gallery" in the "sites" directory on my computer.

Can anyone give me guidance how to load pages (i.e. what to write in the browser). If you need more information about my setup please let me know in the comments.

**Edit**

The guy who did the tutorial accesses his site by

```
http://localhost/~jack/photo_gallery/public
```

Comment: Can you include a link to the tutorial you're following? Also, have you started your web server?

Comment: @David Zaslavsky I've started the webserver. The tutorial is not online so it can't be linked, but I will put his instructions in the OP.

Comment: @Michael: okay, well this will be harder without knowing what exactly the tutorial tells you to do. What is the full path of the file you're trying to access?

Comment: @David Zaslavasky   Users/michaelmitchell/sites/photo_gallery/public

Comment: @Michael: In that case, Geoff has posted a link to a web page that I think should help you out.

Comment: @David Zaslavsky do you know how to find out a shortname?

Comment: You should have mentioned that you are using MAMP.  The tutorials assumes the built in server.  MAMP does not server any files out of the site directory.

Comment: It's the second component of the path, as the article Geoff linked to tells you. Yours would be `michaelmitchell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure you have Personal Web Sharing enabled in system preferences. Take a look at http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/os-x-web-development

Comment: I have MAMP installed, and have been able to access a locallly hosted wordpress site at localhost:8888/wordpress/ so I know everything is working. However, now that I'm creating a new site I don't know what to type in the browser

Comment: IN that case you need to put the files under the MAMP/htdocs directory and not in the sites directory.   It appears the tutorials was written assuming you are running the built in server and not MAMP.

Comment: thanks, but the files are now in the same folder as the working wordpress installation and it's still not working

Comment: Assuming MAMP/htdocs/wordpress and MAMP/htdocs/photo_gallery your url would be http://localhost:8888/photo_gallery

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see it using one of the following schemes:

- http://127.0.0.1/
- http://localhost/
- http://{COMPUTERNAME}.local/

Comment: It looks like you should be able to use: http://localhost/~michaelmitchell/photo_gallery/public have you given that a shot?

Comment: I can access a locally hosted wordpress site using  localhost:8888/wordpress/  but I just can't get this new site

Comment: MAMP would be set up with a different document root, likely not able to access your ~/sites/photo_gallery directory. Where on the filesystem is the working wordpress installation?

Comment: Users/michaelmitchell/documents/workspace   is where the working wordpress installation is.  I've put the new (unworking site) in Users/michaelmitchell/sites/photo_gallery

Comment: Your easiest solution may then be to do this. Copy the photo_gallery folder to /Users/michaelmitchell/documents/workspace/ once you've done that, I would guess you could see it at: http://localhost:8888/photo_gallery/

Comment: it doesn't work. The wordpress site works, but not this new one.

Answer (score 0):

In your Apache conf file, not sure about MAC but may also be httpd.conf, is your host DocumentRoot set to point to the correct directory?

May look something like:

DocumentRoot /Users/jack/sites/photo_gallery